# Comparing aggregated values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I've 3 tables like this:

```
create table garage (id INT);
create table floor (id INT, garage_id INT);
create table parking_spot (id INT, floor_id INT, is_occupied INT);
```

I want to print answer to this question: Is Garage full? In other words, are all the spots occupied?

I know I can run following 2 queries separately.

Following query gives me total spots for the garage:

```
select count(*) from parking_spot ps
  join floor f on ps.floor_id = f.id
  join garage g on f.garage_id = g.id
  where g.id = 2
```

and following gives me count of occupied slots for the garage:

```
select count(*) from parking_spot ps
  join floor f on ps.floor_id = f.id
  join garage g on f.garage_id = g.id
  where g.id = 2 and ps.is_occupied = 1;
```

But I would like to write a **Single** query to compare these two SQLs & print 'Garage is full' or 'Garage is not full'. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to count all records, just check if there is at least one or none unoccupied spaces:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
      select * from parking_spot ps
      join floor f on ps.floor_id = f.id
      join garage g on f.garage_id = g.id
      where g.id = 2 and ( ps.is_occupied <> 1 OR ps.is_occupied IS NULL )
    ) 
  THEN 'Garage is not full' ELSE 'Garage is full'
END;
```

Comment: In a large dataset this should perform faster than the accepted solution, given there is an index on `is_occupied`

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(ps.is_occupied = 0) = 0 as is_full
from parking_spot ps
join floor f on ps.floor_id = f.id
where f.garage_id = 2
```

The  `sum()` gives you the number of free slots. If it is `0` then the garage is full.

Answer (score 0):

I liked answer given above by @juergen-d but for the sake of completeness modified his answer per my requirement:

```
select
  case when sum(ps.is_occupied = 0) = 0 then 'Garage is full'
       else 'Garage is NOT full'
  end
  from parking_spot ps
    join floor f on ps.floor_id = f.id
    where f.garage_id = 2;
```

After further review, it seems 'WHEN EXISTS' performs better cause there's no need to count so I accepted answer given by @krokodilko. Here it is:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
      select * from parking_spot ps
      join floor f on ps.floor_id = f.id
      where f.garage_id = 1 and ( ps.is_occupied <> 1 OR ps.is_occupied IS NULL )
    ) 
  THEN 'Garage is not full' ELSE 'Garage is full'
END;
```

Comment: just a recommendation: keep your display text outside the query, handle the translation in your application code. How will you translate it? Where will you look first when you want to change the text? Separation of concerns. This is display logic.